# Can i put 2 separtors in tLdapInput?

Tags: ldap, talend

I have some rows in tLdapInput that have an other separator. Can i put an other separator in tLdapInput in multi valued field separator attribute ? or how i can do it with an other solution ?

Thanks in advance

Some rows are like this :

```
|ou=ROLE_NIVEAU_3,ou=roles,ou=net,ou=applications,dc=cirra,dc=net ;ou=ROLE_COM_SOUSCRIPTION,ou=roles,ou=net,ou=applications,dc=cirra,dc=net ;
```

and normal rows with no space :

```
|ou=ROLE_GEST_PARC_BANQUE,ou=roles,ou=net,ou=applications,dc=cirra,dc=net;ou=ROLE_NIVEAU_1,ou=roles,ou=net,ou=applications,dc=cirra,dc=net;
```

When i split rows i have null when i get the name and i think is because of the space

Comment: Do you have any regularity regarding the other separator ? For instance, is it always in the same attribute and is it always the same one ?

Comment: yes some rows have a space before the real separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i find the solution just i check the delete spaces in Advanced Settings. Thanks Carassus for the help and have a good day

Answer (score 0):

If it's always in the same attribute and always the same 2 separators, you could use the most common separator in the the tLDAPInput and separate with the other separator in a tMap or a tJavaRow.

In the case you shown, can't you just use ";" and trim the values of all attributes after ?

Comment: Ok i will put the commun separator bu how i can do it in a tMap for the second ? Can you show me an example please ?

Comment: Ok sorry it's in tNormalize i need two separators